# What does それに伴い at the start of a sentence mean?

Tags: usage

I have a sentence that starts with それに伴い which I'm trying to translate. I'm assuming that it's a more polite version of それに伴って. My best guess for the meaning would be "With regard to (a previous subject)" or "In relation to (a previous subject)".

Could anyone give the best way to say this in English with some example sentences.

Comment: Perhaps show a few sentences preceding and succeeding the phrase?

Comment: I've often translated [`それに伴い`](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AB%E4%BC%B4%E3%81%84) as "in accordance with this"/"accordingly", but I don't know if those work in all cases.

Comment: @Flaw I only have the one example, and it's someone else's text so I can't really post it here.

Comment: @cypher "Accordingly" sounds like my feeling for this too.

Comment: それに伴い might be more formal than それに伴って, but they do not differ in politeness.

Comment: I also would encapsulate it's various meanings to "Accordingly." This site [link](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AB%E4%BC%B4%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) is a great tool for translations. What you will find is that it's not a dictionary by any means, but it's a translation site which gives meanings based on the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

`それに伴い` is a more formal way of saying `それに伴って`.
Changing て-form into 連用形 is very common in formal Japanese.

伴う is used to show strong forward correlation, so `それに伴い` would be translated as `Along with that, ….`

Answer (score 2):

I thought a few examples would be nice to get a feeling of when and how to use "~に伴い"　so here they are:

1) (taken from [here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%AE%8C%E5%85%A8%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC2%E7%B4%9A-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E8%A9%A6%E9%A8%93%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96-%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A2%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96%E5%8D%94%E4%BC%9A%E7%95%99%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9/dp/4883190889/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1337015282&sr=8-2), page 6):

円高に伴い、来日する外国人旅行者が少なくなった。

Because of the strength of the yen the number of foreigners visiting Japan has decreased.

2) (taken from [here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%B7%8F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E9%9B%86-2%E7%B4%9A%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%E7%B7%A8-%E4%BD%90%E3%80%85%E6%9C%A8-%E4%BB%81%E5%AD%90/dp/4872176154/ref=sr_1_fkmr3_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337015900&sr=8-1-fkmr3)、page 54):

人口の増加に伴い、資源の消費量も増える。

As the population increases so does the consumption of natural resources. (In the book they translated it as "...of resources also increased." but I think that's slightly off.)